# How to configure OpenVPN server to use custom default gateway?

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I have a vpn server at address `10.1.0.2` and the server have another ip in it's network -- `10.0.0.2` in his subnet (it's a tun2socks router).

But default server's gateway is NOT `10.0.0.2` (and it's ok) but another external IP.

I want all the client's traffic to be forwarded through this ip address -- `10.0.0.2`.

Here is part of my server's config:

```
dev tap0
server-bridge 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0 10.1.0.50 10.1.0.100

push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0" ; now client can ping 10.0.0.2
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.1"
push "dhcp-option WINS 10.1.0.1"
```

in fact i want some like `push "redirect-gateway 10.0.0.2"`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> I want all the client's traffic to be forwarded through this ip address -- 10.0.0.2.
>
> I have a vpn server at address 10.1.0.2 and the server have another ip in it's network -- 10.0.0.2

push a default route to client, so all traffic goes to vpn server.  the vpn server's default route should then be 10.0.0.2/24, so as to forward all the vpn client's traffic along to your router.

> push route "0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.0.2 1"

this would mean all internet traffic would go thru vpn tunnel.   i think what you actually might mean is (so all 10/8 traffic goes thru vpn tunnel, but internet traffic does not):

> push route "10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.1.0.2 1"

in this case, as the vpn server is directly connected to 10.0.0.0/24, you would not need to add a route on the vpn server to 10.0.0.0/24, as it already knows about it.

however, keep in mind, after connecting, the client can simply change their route table, so as to have their default route go elsewhere.